# explode the price sign & the number

Tags: php, regex

how can i explode the `$123` or `USD123` or `CAD$123` or `元123` dynamically into

```
array [0] = "$"
array [1] = 123
```

?

```
$keywords = preg_split("/[^0-9]/", "$123");
```

The above is my testing code, but i can't get `$` in `array[0]`, any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$string = '$123';

$string = preg_match('/^(\D+)(\d+)$/', $string, $match);

echo $match[1]; // $
echo $match[2]; // 123
```

Breakdown:

`^(\D+)` match 1 or more non digit at beggining of string

`(\d+)$` match 1 or more digits until end of string

Answer (score 3):

Try this it would work for all.

```
$str = 'CAD$123';
$num = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$curr = explode($num,$str);

echo 'Your currency is '.$curr[0].' and number is '.$num;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002254/split-currency-and-amount-from-a-string

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
$txt='$123';

  $re1='(\\$)'; # Any Single Character 1
  $re2='(\\d+)';    # Integer Number 1

  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2."/is", $txt, $matches))
  {
      $c1=$matches[1][0];
      $int1=$matches[2][0];
      print "($c1) ($int1) \n";
  }
```

All credits to http://txt2re.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use the preg_match with following regex

```
preg_match('/([^0-9]*)([0-9\.]*)(.*)?/', '$20.99USD', $match);
var_dump($match);
```

The above will produce

```
Array
(
    [0] => $20.99USD
    [1] => $
    [2] => 20.99
    [3] => USD
)
```

It can parse $, 20.99, USD as separate index in an array